# how to get started with cilk++

Tags: cilk-plus

I want to use cilk++ for writing parallel code. I want to know the the simplest way to get started either in windows or ubuntu 10.04.What should I istall to get started with cilk++.
Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

cilk++ is an earlier implementation of the Cilk extension to C++.  It is no longer supported.

Cilk has been implemented in the Intel Composer XE C++ compiler, as well as the "cilkplus" branch of GCC.

I'd start with the article http://www.cilkplus.org/which-license at the Cilk Plus website.  Be aware that the "cilkplus" branch of GCC is off of the GCC 4.8 stream, which is under active development.

- Barry Tannenbaum -
   Intel Cilk Plus Runtime Development

Answer (score 0):

Go here.

[Cilk Plus OSS Website](http://www.cilkplus.org/download#runtime-sources)